# Test fail: object produced no output

Tags: r, unit-testing, automated-tests

I am writing my first testsuite in R and I've come across something I don't quite understand. I've written a function which connects to an API and collects some data. I stored it as an S3 class.

I want to write some tests to make sure my output was correct.

Knowing that if I make a generic call to the API, I should get an expected output. However, I get an "No output error".

```
# IN test_api.R
test_object <- spacejam("2010-01-01", "2010-12-31")

test_that("Output is correct", {
  correct_df <- data.frame("index" = c(1:6), 
                           "time" = c("2010-06-13T16:42Z", "2010-07-30T16:08Z", "2010-08-01T08:10Z",
                                      "2010-08-01T10:20Z", "2010-08-01T11:20Z", "2010-08-01T17:00Z"),
                           "speed" = c(500, 750, 760, 1800, 1300, 550),
                           "type" = c("C", "C", "C", "O", "O", "C"))
  expect_output(head(test_object$data), correct_df)
})
```

The error when running Test Package

```
Failure (test_api.R:33:3): Output is correct
`head(test_object)` produced no output
```

What's produced it if I call `test_object`:

```
> attributes(test_object)
$names
[1] "data"     "response"

$class
[1] "spacejam_API"

> head(test_object$data)
  index              time speed type
1     1 2010-06-13T16:42Z   500    C
2     2 2010-07-30T16:08Z   750    C
3     3 2010-08-01T08:10Z   760    C
4     4 2010-08-01T10:20Z  1800    O
5     5 2010-08-01T11:20Z  1300    O
6     6 2010-08-01T17:00Z   550    C
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: from `?testthat::expect_output` : "Test for output produced by print() or cat(). [...]" -> You'd want to use `expect_equal` or `expect_setequal`

Comment: Ahh. Well that makes sense now =) Thank you